# Controlling buttons in asp.net web application using hand detected by web cam

Tags: asp.net, webcam, silverlight-5.0

I really don't know if this is possible or not. I need to control buttons of an ASP.NET web application when the user hover the hand on buttons. The motion should be captured from the webcam and I don't know if this needs silverlight or not. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight applications run on the client, ASP.NET pages run on the server. You can send data from the calling ASP.NET page to the Silverlight application upon start, but you cannot let the Silverlight app control specific buttons on your ASP.NET page. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [aForge.Net](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)

> AForge.NET Framework is a C# framework designed for developers and researchers in the fields of Computer Vision and Artificial Intelligence - image processing, neural networks, genetic algorithms, machine learning, robotics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a client-side webcam library that you can trigger image capture from webcam by JavaScript  when the user hover the hand on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this. We can do a simple image processing to find out motion in different regions (Buttons). Also have to control the event trigger in time. The start can get from this.[Here it shows how to capture motion with web cam](http://slmotiondetection.codeplex.com/)

then limit the calculation for width and height of the buttons you are using and trigger events if they exceed the threshold.